# Django how to achieve wizard-like flow from one view to another

Tags: django, django-views, user-experience, control-flow

I have a django website with a registration page.

When the user hits the submit button (on /register), I want to validate in the same view (/register). When it does work, I want the user to be taken to another view, to accomplish their next task (/agree), if they have consents to give, or if not, to be taken to a success page telling them they have completed their sign-up.

i.e., their experience should be:

```
/register --- if consents needed ---> /agree ---> /success
  |                                                 ^
  |--- no consent needed ---------------------------|
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? If not, what are good alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a django core tool named "[Form Wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)" which in fact is not very comfortable, but works fine.